# docker ps shows empty list

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I built a docker image from a docker file. Build said it succeeded. But when I try to show docker containers through `docker ps` (also tried `docker ps -a`), it shows an empty list. What is weird is that I'm still able to somehow push my docker image to dockerhub by calling `docker push "container name"`.

I wonder what's going on? I'm on Windows 7, and just installed the newest version of dockertoolbox.

Comment: Same problem Ubuntu22
Docker cant show nvidia-docker containers

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`docker ps` shows (running) containers. `docker images` shows images.

A successfully build docker image should appear in the list which `docker images` generates. But only a running container (which is an instance of an image) will appear in the list from `docker ps` (use `docker ps -a` to also see stopped containers). To start a container from your image, use `docker run`.

Comment: Just want to make this answer more complete for those docker beginners , command `docker ps -a` will list all the containers including the `Exited` and `Dead` containers.

Comment: @mainframer this is extremely helpful. I'm troubleshooting docker for the first time and my container keeps exiting. I couldn't see it without the -a flag.

Comment: It is *very* poor design of `docker` that one needs to add `-a` . Super noobie unfriendly .  I have about 15 containers that I could not find at all.

Comment: On my machine, `docker ps -al` returns only one container, however `docker ps -a -f status=exited` returns all my containers.

Comment: @AdrienPacifico the `-l` flag you used instructs docker to only show the latest created container. If you omit the `-l` (i.e. `docker ps -a`) you should get all containers. The `-f status=exited` filters by status and excludes for example containers in status "Created" or "Dead".

Comment: Oops, I assumed that `l` standed for "list "as in `ls` and not `latest`. @SvenKoschnicke, thank you very much for making me realize that!
Best

Answer (score 42):

For me, `docker ps -a` and `docker images` both returned an empty list even tho I had many docker containers running. I tried rebooting system with no luck. A quick `sudo systemctl restart docker` fixed this "bug".

Comment: If you have an empty list when you know it shouldn't be empty, this is the right answer

Comment: This fixed it for me. Every docker command and portainer interface indicated no containers, networks, or really anything except stacks but portainer itself was running so i knew they were executing. Weird..

Comment: This issues is happening to me every time I reboot my ubuntu box.  Running `sudo systemctl restart docker` always fixes it. But it will go bad again on the next reboot.  Have in mind the docker containers I should be seeing are indeed running, just `docker ps -a` does not list them.  Docker bug?

Comment: unfortunately this seems to stop all running containers. Is there a way to restart docker "seemlessly"?

Comment: `restart docker` alone didn't work for me, though it did try to bring my invisible-but-running container again, which of course failed to bind to the port. (Ubuntu Server 22.04LTS if it matters). I think I only needed to do `sudo systemctl restart docker.socket` after a reboot and it showed the full list again after only a minor blip on the host (not sure if it actually restarts due to the socket restarting).

Comment: Check using snap list if you have docker installe on ubuntu, then remove it with snap remove docker. Snap is an alternate package repository included with ubuntu and some packages overlap with the apt repos.

Answer (score 12):

try restarting

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: This worked for me, I needed to restart docker.socket as well. Thanks.

Comment: This resolved my issue. After doing a reboot from a firmware update docker.socket needed to be restarted. Interestingly, even though the containers came up as non-existent I could still access the Wiki.js site running from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command with the `-D` option (for DEBUG mode) so that additional debug information is displayed in the output.

The application might have failed to start.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I've found a better root cause for the issue where `docker ps` shows an empty list, but the containers are known to be running, at least on Ubuntu Server 22.04 where maybe Docker was installed at initial installation (via Snap?) and again later via the standard instructions (via apt).

The answer comes from here: https://forums.docker.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-unexpected-docker-socket-behaviour-after-boot/134626/3

The gist is that Docker is installed from 2 sources: apt + snap, One starts at boot, and the other replaces it (but doesn't know about the running containers).

Check if this is the case by running these commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep docker
snap list | grep docker
```

If both show docker then this might be the issue.

Remove the snap install with:

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

Once I did the above I received the following output:

```
$> docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

But then I did:

```
$> sudo systemctl restart docker.socket
$> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     ...
ffe52...       container ...
```

And saw my containers.

Also, upon reboot, a simple `docker ps` shows the expected containers instead of an empty list.

Comment: I got that problem after installing `dive` through `snap`. Don't install `dive` through `snap`

Answer (score 2):

For me, the only thing resolving the issue is to reinstall docker. Also, one must be sure that the disk is not full.

This is the command that I use, but it may vary depending on the version of docker already installed:

```
apt-get install --reinstall docker.io
```

If prompted, choose "yes" to automatically restart docker daemon

Answer (score 2):

for Linux,

at first, see all the running container

```
sudo docker ps
```

try restarting

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

remove previous docker image with the same name if there is any

```
sudo docker rm docker_container_id
```

once again run

```
sudo docker run -d --name container_name image_name
```

This should work

or uninstall docker and install it again

Answer (score 0):

In the Dockerfile instructions, make sure the `CMD` commands are in between double-quotes not single-qoute

for example:

`CMD [ "node" , 'index.js']` Here there is a mistake !!

Correct one is :

`CMD [ "node" , "index.js"]`

This mistake will make the container run and exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `Dive-in` extension installed on Docker Desktop, which I suppose had its own image, and the container was running somewhere. When trying to delete that image it would complain that the container was still running, however, the list of containers was empty.

Since I was not using it anymore, I uninstalled the extension and the image was gone.