# Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: permission denied, how to kill docker containers on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kill-process

I'm trying to kill a docker container, but I got permission denied. I use Ubuntu 20.04, my docker version for client is 20.10.7 and the one for the server is 20.10.11.

This is the log I got:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: fastapi_server: permission denied
```

I read that I should use this comand for restarting docker.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service
```

But the thing is that when I execute this command, all my containers and images dissapear, but If I try on localhost:8000 my port is occupied by the container that I wanted to delete. And if I run `sudo netstat -anp | grep 8000`, I get:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    2493/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN    2500/docker-proxy
```

So this confirms that my port is already taken by a docker container, but when I run `docker ps -a`, I get no container. I also tried `docker kill`, but it did not work.

How should I kill this container & get my 8000 port free?

Comment: Is your user in the `docker` group? How did you start the container?

Comment: @tripleee, yes my user is in the `docker` group. I started the container with `docker-compose` . `docker-compose down` is not working too, I got permission denied.

Answer (score 15):

what works for me in these cases:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service
sudo docker image rm -f $(sudo docker image ls -q)
```

Comment: It seems removing the containers is sufficient - no need to remove the images:
`sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service; sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q) -f`

Answer (score 9):

It appeared that I had installed docker with snap as well as using the docker repository:

```
sudo snap list
```

So:

```
sudo snap remove docker --purge
sudo aa-remove-unknown
```

Along with re-installing Docker using the method described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) solved my issues! No need to disable or remove apparmor.

Answer (score 6):

Please think twice before removing `AppArmor`. To my understanding this is central to application security for instance on recent major Ubuntu versions.

It seems the rights problem is specific to a Docker version. Assuming yours is also installed via snap, please attempt upgrading your Docker version to at least the current beta, e.g. with

```
snap refresh docker --beta
```

`20.10.12` seems to work fine.

(In fact I fell for the suggestion and did remove my AppArmor - snaps went away. Then reinstalled ASAP, the settings of relevant snaps are still with me - afterwards installed docker back, had the problem, upgraded it: seems to work like a charm.)

Comment: I upgraded docker engine version to 20.10.12 and everything was going great until I have the same denied permission when killing a container. I would like to know if the next solution would be dangerous too, in this apparmor is not being removed just all profiles that are not stored in /etc/apparmor.d are unloaded. ```sudo aa-remove-unknown```
```docker container kill $(docker ps -q)```.

Comment: And I can even check profiles that are going to be unloaded with `sudo aa-remove-unknown -n`. And with this, I wonder if it is possible to just unload profiles related to docker, just for keeping loaded the rest of the profiles.

Comment: There are (at least) two very different approaches to take IMHO.

#1 is to stick with the snapped Docker. I think having to follow distro-specific instructions, howtos etc. is a major blocker of Linux adoption. Push harder or avoid - I'll try to push harder (will follow up).

Or: #2 install the absolute latest Docker , which means you can uninstall the snap.
https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-stop-docker-container-permission-denied-error/41142/33

Maybe you should go with #2? I no longer experience the problem but would be keen to hear back from you whichever way you choose to go.

Comment: For #2:

This is what I received "I know this topic is not about Docker installation, but I would not recommend installing Docker from snap repository. I understand that it seems easier, but you can (but not necessarily will) have more problems later. Use the recommended way by the Documentation depending on which distribution you use."

Maybe the best advice for you?

Comment: For #1: I thought I'd raise this on the Snapcraft forums - maybe they'll be quicker with the beta to release path.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-snap-problem-with-stopping-containers-20-10-11/29204

I'm uncertain what to say on the solution you propose unfortunately. (Will try to think about it I just don't have too much time on my hands right now.)

Comment: (Quick update: I got a reply on the Snapcraft forums in the meantime pointing to https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/36, the workaround I saw there is `sudo rm /var/snap/docker/common/profile_reloaded`, I don't know how you decided, this might be along the lines of your approach, might even help or unblock you, what I like about it is that it explicitly targets `docker` at some point. Must say I don't know what either does, without that I was a bit worried to nod :) .)

Comment: Not sure if it helps you, but in the end (on my side) - I was simply stupid :) My problem came back too. `docker --version` (did you try it by the way?) kept saying `20.10.7` to me but I couldn't remove docker (`sudo apt remove docker`) and thus I thought it's just a glitch with the snap or similar. And was I wrong! `sudo apt list --installed | grep docker` gave away that I had a version installed from `apt` in parallel. I removed that and it all got solved. (It was docker.io for me from some PPA I think for a course... at some point...)

Comment: thanks for following up. I finally deleted my docker.io, and reinstalled docker as follow: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/. I hope this works well in the long run, if I have any new issues or updates on the issue I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

```
docker inspect
```

Find the PID AND kill that process.

If that does not work check with

```
dmesg
```

everything related to Docker. You can put output here that we can help you.

Ok,from you png ist seems that you have problem with AppArmor. Try this:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove apparmor
sudo service docker restart
docker system prune --all --volumes
```

Comment: this is all related to docker that I got when running `dmesg`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XI_P0TgpTZ2_GEX-LdEPo9FhylYdpzzo/view?usp=sharing (sorry for showing an image for the console log, but I thought this was better to show like this on a comment). `docker insepct` did not work, because according to `docker` I have no processes running.

Comment: It works, but I wonder if deleting apparmor security module does not end up being counterproductive or damaging something?, although I finally reinstalled this module

Comment: Should be OK. Read more https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Comment: Please update your answer and warn the readers about this caveat so I can be less negative too. Have you tried downgrading perhaps? Sounds like a new problem or one that is re-emerging.

Comment: (Everybody: please do not remove AppArmor, especially on a Ubuntu - it will remove all of your snaps as part of the removal of Snap.)

Comment: @brezniczky where can I read more about AppArmor?

Comment: I used apt for install.

Comment: Good question, I know and agree AppArmor causes problems as a snap developer. Snaps are now underpinning the whole Ubuntu Software Center to my understanding ... so there can be problems if people remove AppArmor ;) )

I am not an expert (too much hair I don't even have has been pulled out on the way there :) ), but despite my shallow understanding I have some hope this helps:

https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

Comment: Sorry the marketing stuff, this has just got in my way ... looks like Canonical are serious about AppArmor

https://ubuntu.com/engage/apparmor-intro

Answer (score 0):

I installed Docker from snap and experienced the permission denied error response. After reading many users experiencing more problems with the apparmor suggestion, I uninstalled Docker from snap, then used [digitalocean's Docker installation tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04#step-3-using-the-docker-command).

It worked for me, posting here as reference for others experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was also apparmor on Ubuntu 20.04 after upgrade from Bionic. By running dmesg I got error message:

```
[1113458.482007] audit: type=1400 audit(1672134271.112:1718): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="docker-default" pid=1654 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="receive" denied_mask="receive" signal=kill peer="snap.docker.dockerd
```

To fix this please edit /etc/apparmor.d/docker and add to the beginning (however, after the 'profile docker-default .... {' ) the following line:

```
 signal,
```

Then reload apparmor

```
 sudo systemctl reload apparmor
```

This fixed it at least on my computer.

See more https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/apparmor.d.5.html under section signal:

```
Example AppArmor signal rules:

       # Allow all signal access
       signal,
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; it turned out that I had two docker installations. I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77555447/6380031) answer, but in a nutshell there are two installations for docker, one from `apt` and another from `snap`. You need to remove the one from `snap`, and just keep the one with `apt`. Instructions are in the link.